# Multithreading in C++: The correct way to join threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

I am new to multithreading so any suggestions would be appreciated. The following program takes in a vector of integers(eg. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7) and processes each of them as threads. I was wondering if the method with which I join the threads is correct, and if I can make any improvements.

I hope my explanation is clear! Here is my code snippet. It's not the  complete code, I'm just ensuring I'm going the right way:

```
    //vector's name is 'inputs' and it contains integers

    for (int unsigned i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
        thread thread_obj(thread_function, inputs.at(i));  
        thread_obj.detach();
        
    }
    
    for (int unsigned i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
      thread_obj.join();
    }
```

Comment: The code as is wont even compile.  Do you have a working version or are you just checking if this is the right way to go?

Comment: You are detaching the threads and then trying to join. That won't work. Once you detach you don't need to join.

Comment: @jignatius -- or, rather, don't detach; join. Detaching is rarely appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior so no, it is not correct.  The issue here is that you can only call `join()` if `joinable()` is `true` and because you called `detach()`, `joinable()` will return `false`.

The good news is it is really quite a simple fix.  You just need to remove the call to `detach`.  To complete out the code just populate a vector of threads and then join them all like

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
threads.reserve(inputs.size());
for (int unsigned i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
    threads.push_back(std::thread{thread_function, inputs.at(i)};  
}
// now all threads are running, or waiting to run
for (int unsigned i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
    threads[i].join();
}
// now all threads have been joined
```